# My beagle bone black doesn't boot from s.d card?

Tags: beagleboneblack

I put the SD card in the sd slot and tried to boot by pressing the S2 button while I connect the beaglebone black element 14 board to the usb for power the four led's began to flash but the image won't display on the screen.

Comment: What exactly is on that SD card?  Perhaps it's not set up correctly, perhaps it just copies the OS image it contains onto the BB's internal storage and never displays anything on its own.

Comment: Also it's always good to be able to examine the debug UART output. Given that usb-to-UART converters cost less than 1€/$/£ there is no excuse to not having at least one.